# Trailing Slash on Links pages not opening

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

Can I just get a definitive answer from you guys.

If I have a file called index.php in a folder called about should I link using a trailing slash for example:

```
<a href="/about/"></a>
```

or

```
<a href="/about"></a>
```

Finally, one of my clients using IE9 is saying that certain links are not opening, I've tried with an without the slash.

Is there anything I could add to my `.htaccess` to sort this out?

I've tested the page in question and it seems fine for me but you know what clients are like, he wants it working on his PC.

Comment: Sorry my code snippets got stripped out, you know what I mean anyway I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

When a web server receives a request ending in a / it will serve the default page as in the configuration or default.

You can configure this in an .htaccess file or in the core config for Apache, using the [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html) directive.

There is also a directive [DirectorySlash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) that specifies whether to serve the index file when requesting a directory name.  If you turn this off then you may see an autoindex page instead.  Apache recommend that you don't turn this off without a good reason.

To be on the safe side, always include the trailing / or link specifically to the intended index file for the directory.

If you are using a different web server, please update your question.

Comment: Hi thanks very much for replying. I am using Apache on a Linux server. I've added the slash now. My client can access every page on the site apart from this http://www.jaybe.com/folding-beds/ can you think of any reason why this could be?

Comment: I've decided to use DirectoryIndex index.php, to see if this solves the issue. Could this be added to the htaccess file in the root of the site to force index.php to be the default for all folders?

Comment: Yes - in the Apache documentation the Context line for each directive shows where you can use it.  In this case you can use it in the main section of the config file, within a Virtual Host or Directory config, or in an .htaccess file.